# Is it possible to build a server side installable WEB application in php that can not be copied at all

Tags: php, web-applications, installation

I got a requirement document by client & have to build a product for client which client will sell to their merchants and the requirement is they want the product to be installable on merchants server providing that the merchant cannot copy/paste it and sell it to others by changing the copyright. Is it possible bcoz i havent came across this kind of requirement before & if it is possible then what are the things need to be implemented to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a tool like [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard) which will obfuscate your code and enforce licensing.